# PropertyInfo - GetProperties with attributes

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm trying to create a custom attribute validation for a webform projects.

I already can get all properties from my class, but now i don't know how to filter them and just get the properties that has some attribute.

For example:

```
PropertyInfo[] fields = myClass.GetType().GetProperties();
```

This will return me all the properties. But how can i just return the properties using a attribute like "testAttribute", for example?

I've already searched about this but after a few time trying to solve this i decided to ask here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fields.Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).Length > 0)
```

See [documentation for `GetCustomAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to use the GetCostumAttributes, but i wasn't making the Lenght > 0 condition. You solved it mate ;)

Answer (score 24):

Use `Attribute.IsDefined`:

```
PropertyInfo[] fields = myClass.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(TestAttribute), false))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is a better answer: no need to count when we just need an existence check.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
    .Any()
```

and simplify expression

```
    fields.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).Any())
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx) method of MemberInfo. If you are looking specifically for say, TestAttribute, you can use:

```
foreach (var propInfo in fields) {
    if (propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).Count() > 0) {
        // Do some stuff...
    }      
}
```

Or if you just need to get them all:

```
var testAttributes = fields.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).Count() > 0);
```

Comment: Use Any() instead of Count() > 0